# ionic - how to translate date month names in ionic 4?

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm displaying data this way:

```
{{ this.setupData.league?.date_start | date: 'dd/MM' }}
```

It's working good, but now I'm trying to translate month names, day names, etc...

How can I do this in Ionic 4?

Answer (score 2):

Massive subject area but in short I assume that the textual representations of dates will be rendered by default as per the language settings on the device. However if you want to manually control the language from within your app then I would strongly suggest looking at  [ngx-translate](http:///https://github.com/ngx-translate/core).

This will enable you to setup language packs in JSON format and then you can use the dependency injected Translation Service to extract the relevant language for the selected language code, this you will need to setup in your code e.g. en, de, es, fr etc.

I haven't added a specific example as the documentation provided is excellent and you should see how you can further utilize this component to provide a complete multi-lingual solution for your app.